# How to destructure a pair in lambda arguments

Tags: c++, lambda, structured-bindings

When I use for-loop I can destructure the arguments right away, e.g.

```cpp
for(const auto & [key, value] : myMap) { }
```

But can I do the same in lambda? (obviously not like this, this won't compile)

```cpp
std::for_each(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), [](const auto & [key, value]) { });
```